# setCustomValidity() html5 function is not working properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i am using `setCustomValidity()` for adding custom error message for mobile number validation.its not working properly. if enter any invalid number or character it showing the error message as i specified,but after entering the valid information its not clearing the error message and stopping my ajax call.
 here is my html

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <input type="tel" name="tel" pattern="[0-9]{10}" class="form-control input-lg" id="tel"  placeholder="Mobile" >
    </div>
```

here is the script

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        //mobile number validation

        var input = document.getElementById('tel');
    input.oninvalid = function(event) {

        event.target.setCustomValidity('mobile number must contain 10 digits , alphabets & specila characters are not allowd');
    }
        //ajax call to send mail
         $("#btn").click(function(){ 

                $.ajax({      
                    url:"SendEmail",
                    data:"&FirstName="+ $("#FirstName").val()+"&LastName="+ $("#LastName").val()+"&email="+ $("#email").val()+"&tel="+ $("#tel").val()+"&text="+ $("#text").val(),
                    dataType:"json",  
                    type:"get",  
                    success:function(response){    
                        console.log(response); 

                                                }


             });
            });
    });
```

whats wrong with it?

Comment: You don't get any errors in the console ? if the validation work as expected maybe something is with your ajax call

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
 <input type="tel" name="tel" pattern="[0-9]{10}" class="form-control input-lg"
  id="tel" placeholder="Mobile" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('mobile number must 
  contain 10 digits ...')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')"/>
</div>
```

Comment: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/forms/constraintvalidation/
This might help :)